# Unable to read JSON with X-Editable/jQuery, Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, x-editable

I've been trying to figure out why this isn't working for way too long now. Figure it's time to ask for help.

I have Javascript that uses [X-Editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/). My page submits an AJAX request to my server. My server responds with JSON containing the db key. Only problem is, Chrome doesn't recognize the JSON.

Development Tools shows the response as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Oct 2014 20:04:12 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 30
Server: Jetty(7.6.13.v20130916)

{"success":true,"actionid":66}
```

I don't think having success in there is spec, but X-Editable makes reference to it. I've tried having it in and out and it doesn't make any difference.

The below function handles submitting the AJAX request and handles success/failure. Only, the success routine isn't getting called for some reason.

```
$('#save-btn').click(function() {
    $('.new-link-param').editable('submit', {
        url: '/newlink',
        ajaxOptions: {
            type: 'post'
        },
        success: function (data, config) {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            // console.log(data.actionid);
            // console.log(typeof data);
            // if(data && data.actionid){ // assumes response like {"actionid": 2}
            //     alert(true);
            //     $(this).editable('option', 'actionid', data.actionid);
            //     $(this).removeClass('editable-unsaved');
            //     var msg = "Link saved.";
            //     $('#msg').addClass('alert-success').remove.Class('hidden').removeClass('alert-error').html(msg).show();
            //     $(this).off('save.newuser');
            // }
            // else if(data && data.errors){
            //     config.error.call(this, data.errors);
            //}
            alert(true);
        },
        error: function(errors) {
            alert(false);
            var msg = "";
            if(errors && errors.responseText){
                msg = errors.responseText;
            } else {
            console.log("Error: " + errors.responseText);
            }
}}).editable('destroy').removeClass().removeAttr('id').parent().parent().children("button").remove();
});
}
```

Earlier in the day, the success function *was* getting called, but the if statement inside was returning false as although data existed. For some reason, data.actionid was undefined. Not sure why this changed. I would think given the response I pasted above that it should be getting hit.

I'm wondering what I need to do in order for the JS code to register successful and recognize the JSON returned to it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I needed to have specified `ajaxOptions{ dataType: 'json'}`.